# jQuery autoGrow textarea completely browser compatible

Tags: jquery, plugins, textarea, autogrow

I've been trying to find a good jquery auto grow plugin but every single one I find either doesn't work correctly in all browser, (up to date ones, not so worried about older browsers), or they don't allow me to put my own css height/width etc. to them. I just want a simple one that works, I don't want any fancy animations, (unless that plugin works great), one I have had worked perfect in firefox, however in webkit it would autogrow when you typed, even before the text got to the end of the line, and then another autogrow one wouldn't allow me to set the height/width to specific values.

Comment: Great; so...what've you tried to do to correct that? What plug-ins have you tried looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, this does what I need.
http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/jquery-grab-bag/autogrow-textarea.html